I/O-bandwidth gap between GPU-POSIX and CPU-POSIX
Im using fio to compare storage bandwidths on a compute node (1 NVIDIA H100-SXM5 and 1 CPU with 64 cores). When comparing CPU posix (aio_write/aio_read) with GPU posix (pread/pwrite + cudaMemcpy), I get around 8 GiB/s (read) at peak (tested with multiple batch size and thread) for posixaio and around 30 GiB/s (read) for GPU-POSIX (libcufile posix). Im wondering why the GPU measurement is much more performant than the CPU POSIX, even though there is more work being done for GPU-POSIX: A pread() to a CPU buffer and then a cudaMemcpy() to the GPU, compared to a aio_read() to the CPU. Here are my fio commands:
CPU-POSIX:
fio --ioengine=posixaio --direct=1 --bs="$batch_size"k --size=50G --runtime=30 --time_based --name=job --filename=testfile --rw=randread  \
       --numjobs="$threads" --thread --group_reporting --output-format=json --output=reports_cpu/"$batch_size"/"$threads"/cpu_posix_r

GPU-POSIX:
fio --ioengine=libcufile --cuda_io=posix --direct=1 --bs="$batch_size"k --size=50G -runtime=30 --time_based --gpu_dev_ids="0" --name=job \
        --rw=randread --thread --numjobs="$threads" --group_reporting --output=gpu_reports/"$batch_size"/"$threads"/gpu_r --output-format=json

I tested for different I/O batch sizes ($batch_size) and different threads ($threads). The node was exclusively allocated for this measurement, so I could rule out interference from other workloads. Im using CUDA-12.4.0. Are there other factors Im missing out on?
